# Created an object in my index.js file, how to make it available in a router file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have an `index.js` file where I:

- initialize my Express app instance
- include a `router.js` file that defines a POST endpoint
- create a Socket.IO object

code as follows:

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const router = require("./src/router");


// Create Express webapp
const app = express();

// Create http server and run it
const server = http.createServer(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Create Socket.IO instance
const io = require('socket.io')(server,{
  cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:3000",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      credentials:true
  }
});
const cors = require('cors');
```

At the POST endpoint in `router.js`, I want to use the Socket.IO object like this:

```
const Router = require("express").Router;    
const router = new Router();

router.post("/call",(req, res)=>{
  let data = req.body;
  let response = {
    something:`${data.userID} requested a call length ${data.minutes}`
  }
  io.broadcast.emit(response);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
});

module.exports = router;
```

But this gives me the error:

```
ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

How do I make the `io` object available to this `router.post()` call?  I tried making it a global in `index.js` via:

```
global.io = io;
```

but then the POST call gave me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

also tried including `io` as a parameter in the `module.exports` function like:

```
const Router = require('express').Router;
const { tokenGenerator, voiceResponse } = require('./handler');

module.exports = function(io) {
  const router = new Router();
  router.post('/call', (req, res)=>{
    const data = req.body;
    const response = {
      something: `${data.userID} requested a call length ${data.minutes}`,
    }
    io.broadcast.emit(response);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
  });
  return router;
}
```

and then requiring the router in `index.js` like:

```
const router = require('./src/router')(io);
```

but that gave the same `Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message carefully.

> but that gave the same Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined error.

You are successfully passing `io`.

The problem is that `io.broadcast` is `undefined` so it can't have an `emit` property.

You can find `broadcast` on [a socket object](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#flag-broadcast), not on the server object itself.